# ajax in a loop without correct value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I got a problem with ajax in a loop.
I found the loop variable "i" did not increase.
Supposed there were 3 items in the array1, the script would alert 4,4,4
But not 1,2,3 as I expected.
Could someone give me a hint?
Many thanks.

```
var i;
for(i=1;i<=array1.length;i++){
tmp=array1[i-1];
$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_feedback.php",
    data: {id : tmp.id},
    success: function(msg)
    {   
        alert(i);
    }
});
}
```

Comment: it is because 'success' is a function which is called after the response comes from the server. At the time when response arrives, for loop would be done and value of i is length of the array. And i is in [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures)

Comment: add `asyn:false` in the ajax, so loop will wait till it get response.

Comment: oh god! async:false works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution for this problem is :

```
var i;
for(i=1;i<=array1.length;i++){
tmp=array1[i-1];

ajaxCall(i);

}

function ajaxCall(i){

$.ajax
({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax_feedback.php",
    data: {id : tmp.id},
    success: function(msg)
    {   
    alert(i);
    }
});

}
```

Whenever you are making ajax call in loop.Never try to call it directly.It is because ajax call is asynchronous and till the time success code come back from server,i value get incremented and because of which,it is showing 4,4,4 as output in alerts.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var len = array1.length;
show(0);
function show(i){
    var tmp=array1[i-1];
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax_feedback.php",
        data: {id : tmp.id},
        error:function(){
            if(i < len){
                show(i+1);
            }
        },
        success: function(msg){   
            alert(i);
            if(i < len){
                show(i+1);
            }
        }
    });
}
```